# Which one should I use? (Need opinions) CSS class

Tags: html, css, markup

I have the options to choose between those CSS classes:

```
.container> div > table.Test> tbody > .header
```

And

```
.header
```

to add some CSS styling.

**What I would like to know about this is:**

1. What is the main difference?
2. Which do you prefer to use, and why?
3. Is there a different in performance between those two?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the FAQs.

Comment: The difference depends on how your HTML and your CSS is build. The first is more specific which may overrule the second. Read about [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to learn more about that. I prefer to keep everything simple, the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). But again, it depends on the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the question doesnt make any sense.

**Explanation:**

**1.What is the main difference?**

```
div#container > ul 
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The difference between the standard X Y and X > Y is that the latter will only select direct children. For example, consider the following markup.

```
 <div id="container">
   <ul>
   <li> List Item
    <ul>
       <li> Child </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> List Item </li>
  <li> List Item </li>
  <li> List Item </li>
```

A selector of #container > ul will only target the uls which are direct children of the div with an id of container. It will not target, for instance, the ul that is a child of the first li.

```
 .header
 {
 }
```

It will target all the elements with the class header.

```
 #container > div > .header
 {
 }
```

It will target all header elements which is directly placed under the divs which are directly placed under #container.

**2.Which do you prefer to use, and why?**

It mainly depends on your need. If you want to target all header elements[i.e There may be many tables with same class .header] If you want to apply styles to all the headers, you can use second way. Else use first way.

**3.Performance**

I am not sure. I don't find any performance issues.